# Reading an Encrypted data from a txt file and decrypting it in ios

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, aes

**I Using AES128 Encryption and Decryption Technique for reading an encrypted text from a Text File 
and Decrypting but i am unable to decrypt it.
The Data in Text file is Encrypted using AES128 in C#**

I am using the following code to decrypt it

Kindly help i am new to Encryption and Decryption in AES12*

```
- (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)plainText key:(NSData *)aSymmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt padding:(CCOptions *)pkcs7
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus = kCCSuccess;
    // Symmetric crypto reference.
    CCCryptorRef thisEncipher = NULL;
    // Cipher Text container.
    NSData * cipherOrPlainText = nil;
    // Pointer to output buffer.
    uint8_t * bufferPtr = NULL;
    // Total size of the buffer.
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    // Remaining bytes to be performed on.
    size_t remainingBytes = 0;
    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
    size_t movedBytes = 0;
    // Length of plainText buffer.
    size_t plainTextBufferSize = 0;
    // Placeholder for total written.
    size_t totalBytesWritten = 0;
    // A friendly helper pointer.
    uint8_t * ptr;

    // Initialization vector; dummy in this case 0's.
    uint8_t iv[kChosenCipherBlockSize];
    memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));

    NSLog(@"doCipher: plaintext: %@", plainText);
    NSLog(@"doCipher: key length: %d", [aSymmetricKey length]);

    //LOGGING_FACILITY(plainText != nil, @"PlainText object cannot be nil." );
    //LOGGING_FACILITY(aSymmetricKey != nil, @"Symmetric key object cannot be nil." );
    //LOGGING_FACILITY(pkcs7 != NULL, @"CCOptions * pkcs7 cannot be NULL." );
    //LOGGING_FACILITY([aSymmetricKey length] == kChosenCipherKeySize, @"Disjoint choices for key size." );

    plainTextBufferSize = [plainText length];//+kCCBlockSizeAES128;

    //LOGGING_FACILITY(plainTextBufferSize > 0, @"Empty plaintext passed in." );

    NSLog(@"pkcs7: %d", *pkcs7);
    // We don't want to toss padding on if we don't need to
    if(encryptOrDecrypt == kCCEncrypt)
    {
        if(*pkcs7 != kCCOptionECBMode)
        {
            if((plainTextBufferSize % kChosenCipherBlockSize) == 0)
            {
                *pkcs7 = 0x0000;
            }
            else
            {
                *pkcs7 = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(encryptOrDecrypt != kCCDecrypt)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid CCOperation parameter [%d] for cipher context.", *pkcs7 );
    }

    // Create and Initialize the crypto reference.
    ccStatus = CCCryptorCreate(encryptOrDecrypt,
                               kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                               *pkcs7,
                               (const void *)[aSymmetricKey bytes],
                               kChosenCipherKeySize,
                               (const void *)iv,
                               &thisEncipher
                               );

    //LOGGING_FACILITY1( ccStatus == kCCSuccess, @"Problem creating the context, ccStatus == %d.", ccStatus );

    // Calculate byte block alignment for all calls through to and including final.
    bufferPtrSize = CCCryptorGetOutputLength(thisEncipher, plainTextBufferSize, true);

    // Allocate buffer.
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t) );

    // Zero out buffer.
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);

    // Initialize some necessary book keeping.

    ptr = bufferPtr;

    // Set up initial size.
    remainingBytes = bufferPtrSize;

    // Actually perform the encryption or decryption.
    ccStatus = CCCryptorUpdate(thisEncipher,
                               (const void *) [plainText bytes],
                               plainTextBufferSize,
                               ptr,
                               remainingBytes,
                               &movedBytes
                               );

    //LOGGING_FACILITY1( ccStatus == kCCSuccess, @"Problem with CCCryptorUpdate, ccStatus == %d.", ccStatus );

    // Handle book keeping.
    ptr += movedBytes;
    remainingBytes -= movedBytes;
    totalBytesWritten += movedBytes;

    /* From CommonCryptor.h:

     @enum      CCCryptorStatus
     @abstract  Return values from CommonCryptor operations.

     @constant  kCCSuccess          Operation completed normally.
     @constant  kCCParamError       Illegal parameter value.
     @constant  kCCBufferTooSmall   Insufficent buffer provided for specified operation.
     @constant  kCCMemoryFailure    Memory allocation failure.
     @constant  kCCAlignmentError   Input size was not aligned properly.
     @constant  kCCDecodeError      Input data did not decode or decrypt properly.
     @constant  kCCUnimplemented    Function not implemented for the current algorithm.

     enum {
     kCCSuccess          = 0,
     kCCParamError       = -4300,
     kCCBufferTooSmall   = -4301,
     kCCMemoryFailure    = -4302,
     kCCAlignmentError   = -4303,
     kCCDecodeError      = -4304,
     kCCUnimplemented    = -4305
     };
     typedef int32_t CCCryptorStatus;
     */

    // Finalize everything to the output buffer.
    ccStatus = CCCryptorFinal(thisEncipher,
                              ptr,
                              remainingBytes,
                              &movedBytes
                              );

    totalBytesWritten += movedBytes;

    if(thisEncipher) {
        (void) CCCryptorRelease(thisEncipher);
        thisEncipher = NULL;
    }

    //LOGGING_FACILITY1( ccStatus == kCCSuccess, @"Problem with encipherment ccStatus == %d", ccStatus );

    if (ccStatus == kCCSuccess)
        cipherOrPlainText = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)totalBytesWritten];
    else
        cipherOrPlainText = nil;

    if(bufferPtr) free(bufferPtr);
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cipherOrPlainText encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return cipherOrPlainText;

    /*
     Or the corresponding one-shot call:

     ccStatus = CCCrypt(    encryptOrDecrypt,
     kCCAlgorithmAES128,
     typeOfSymmetricOpts,
     (const void *)[self getSymmetricKeyBytes],
     kChosenCipherKeySize,
     iv,
     (const void *) [plainText bytes],
     plainTextBufferSize,
     (void *)bufferPtr,
     bufferPtrSize,
     &movedBytes
     );
     */
}
```

Comment: Could you please post also C# code?

Comment: You can't decide on padding based on mod, it is not possible to tell on decrypt if there is padding. Just choose padding in all cases if it is needed in any case.

Comment: If the data, mode, algorithm, key, iv, are all the same the decryption will work. A good start is to do a hex dump on these the data, key and  iv on both sides.

Comment: Your code is overly complicated for what it is trying to do. The more complicated the greater change for an error.